# Java automatically convert interface to subtype

Tags: java, java-17

So I came across a problem where I have implemented a method for all 4 subtypes of an interface. However, when calling that method with a variable that is of the supertype, it won't let me. I can explicitly use instanceof to check with one, but I need to implement a function that calls 2 instances of the interface.

I already tried checking the 2 instances separately and casting them, but it doesn't work. A solution would be to create if-else with 16 branches to check each combination, but that isn't ideal.

```
public interface FormulaVisitor <Result , AdditionalArg > {
    
    Result visit(Atom formula, AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(BinaryOperator formula , AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(Constant formula , AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(Not formula , AdditionalArg a);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: There are only two options: [1] 'MathOperator' or whatever that common supertype is, by its nature, _always_ has that operation - any imaginable subtype of it should have it. In which case, add it to the interface. [2] 'MathOperator' instances don't necessarily have that - just those 4 subtypes have it. In which case, java is correct: You can't just call that method on any `MathOperator` - even if the 4 impls you have so far do so happen to have em.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a `Formula` interface which is implemented by `Atom`, `Constant`, `BinaryOperator` and `Not`.

So create a method in your visitor which accepts a `Formula` and then delegate to other methods. So I would write something like:

```
public interface FormulaVisitor <Result , AdditionalArg> {
    default Result visit(Formula formula, AdditionalArg a) {
        return switch(formula) {
            case Atom atom -> visit(atom, a);
            case Constant constant -> visit(constant, a);
            case BinaryOperator binaryOperator -> visit(binaryOperator, a);
            case Not not -> visit(not, a);
            default -> null; // if your Formula interface is sealed to 4 classes, this line is not needed
        }
    }

    Result visit(Atom formula, AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(BinaryOperator formula, AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(Constant formula, AdditionalArg a);
    Result visit(Not formula, AdditionalArg a);
}
```

If your interface has just these 4 implementations, make it `sealed`!

As it's a default method in your interface, your are not forced to re-implement it in sub-classes.

In Java method calls are binded during compile time, so the subtype is not recognized then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `Atom`, `BinaryOperator` etc having a common supertype and you know only the common supertype: You're out of luck - you can't simply call those 4 methods and hope for the best:

The exact function that's called is determined statically, at compile time.

If you intend to implement the full [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), you'd have the 4 types implement the call to an appropriate visit method, e.g. by the common supertype declaring `accept(Visitor visitor)`, and implementing the proper call in each subtype.

Comment: Alright, thank you. My classmate seemed to say something similar, we have an accept in Atom, BinaryOperator, etc.